# How can the height of CKEditor text areas be controlled?

Tags: wysiwyg

In Drupal 8.2, this worked:

```
function MYMODULE_editor_js_settings_alter(array &$settings) {
  if (isset($settings['editor']['formats']['simple_formatted_text'])) {
    $settings['editor']['formats']['simple_formatted_text']['editorSettings']['height'] = 80;
  }
}
```

This stopped affecting the height in Drupal 8.3.

CKEditor 4 [documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_size) mentions using config.width and config.height. It seems like I just need to find the right part of the `$settings` array to add a height property. Inside `editorSettings` there is a `customConfig` item which is a string. I've tried some things in there but haven't landed on something that works yet.

Comment: AFAIK, the Autogrow plugin was brought into Drupal 8.3 for CKEditor which should let you set a minimum height as well as "grow" with the editor as content is added. If that is not sufficient, I had a module up until now - I do not know if there is feature parity with it or if this still works in 8.3: https://www.drupal.org/project/autogrow